# Права пользователя в телеграм боте (C#)

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Делаю телеграм бота. Надо создать права для каждого пользователя, к примеру чтобы пользователь не мог перейти из главного меню в другое просто написав: "Другой меню".
Попытался сделать так, но ничего не вышло, если у одного пользователя были права на другое меню, то у всех появлялись права на это:
Класс пользователя:

```
class user
{
    public string userName;
    public List<bool> permissions;
    public long chatId;

    public bool logined = false;
    public user(string a, List<bool> b, long c, bool f)
    {
        userName = a;
        permissions = b;
        chatId = c;
        logined = f;
    }
}
```

Метод для нахождения пользователя:

```
public static user FindUser(string userName)
{
    foreach (user u in users)
    {
        if (u.userName == userName)
        {
            return u;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Создание пользователя:

```
if (FindUser(e.Message.From.Username) == null)
{
    users.Add(new user(e.Message.From.Username, standart_Permissions, e.Message.Chat.Id, false));
}
```

Вот так я задаю право:

```
//GameBot Permissions
//0 - Вход
FindUser(e.Message.From.Username).permissions[0] = true;
```

Comment: Вы много рассказали про то, как у вас создаются права и это полезный и нужный код для понимания вопроса. Однако вы не привели код, который проверяет права -- и если вы хотите понять, почему у вас проверка не проверяет, то без этого кода не обойтись. Добавьте в вопрос, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уточните как хранятся пользователи, если users - List или хранилище, которое кэширует пользователей в том же списке, то создание

```
users.Add(new user(... standart_Permissions ...);
```

А затем изменение через

```
FindUser(e.Message.From.Username).permissions[0] = true;
```

Вызовет изменение списка standart_Permissions и выдаст права для всех пользователей, так как List - ссылочный тип.  (Принципы работы ссылочных типов можно почитать, например, тут - https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/2.16.php)

Для того чтобы этого избежать, нужно пересоздавать список прав, например, стандартным методом .ToList() -

```
users.Add(new user(... standart_Permissions.ToList() ...);
```

Comment: Спасибо, заработало.